# Deploying InfoPathForm to Web

Tags: 2010, development, infopath, forms-services

I deploy a Infopath form to my SiteCollection with a Module. When i want to deploy my solution i get following error:

> An object of the type Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Administration.FormTemplate named "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:MyFunnyForm:-myXSD-2010-04-22T12-54-38" already exists under the parent Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm named "SharePoint_Config". Rename your object or delete the existing object.

So i thought:"Cool, i can just delete the existing form".
So when I tried to delete the form in "Central Administration > Manage Form Templates" i get another error:

> This form template was deployed as part of the SNB.PBL_InfoPath feature. This form template should be removed only by uninstalling that feature.

But there is no feature for this form.

Is there a way to delete this form (commandline, special trick, anything,....)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can try:
1. Rename the InfoPath Form's Namespace (in the File Properties Menu, you can find it);
2. Findout the deprecated feature and remove it. But first, you need to find out it and its ID. Here I found a nice page has the detail: https://dotnetmafia.sys-con.com/node/1665075/mobile . (I got an certificate warning for the page, but seems ok to open it).

Comment: i wasn't able to resolve the problem. i had to recreate my sitecollection :(